# How to create color PDF using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript, visual-foxpro, postscript

In Windows 10 `Infotec MP C7500 PS` printer driver is used to create .ps file from Visual FoxPro application.

This file is converted to pdf using 32bit GhostScript 9.20 in Windows 10.
In one computer created pdf file is monochrome.
How to create color pdf in this computer ?
I verified that Infotec printer is set to produce color output.
I removed printer driver and installed it again but problem persists.

For example, source (below) contains red word Test but it appears as Black in result pdf.
How to fix this so that color pdf can created ?
Ghostscript options used:

```
-dNOPAUSE
-dBATCH
-dSAFER
-r300
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-sOutputFile=result.pdf
-dAutoFilterColorImages=false
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false
-dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode
-dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged
-dDownsampleMonoImages=false
-dDownsampleGrayImages=false
-dDownsampleColorImages=false
-c
.setpdfwrite
-f source.pdf
```

source file:

```
%-12345X@PJL JOB
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = POSTSCRIPT 
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: C:\Users\andrus\AppData\Local\Temp\$_4S418H866.FRX
%%Creator: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
%%CreationDate: 11/19/2016 20:45:6
%%For: andrus
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%DocumentNeededResources: (atend)
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%TargetDevice: (infotec MP C7500 PS3) (3017.104) 2
%%LanguageLevel: 3
%%EndComments

%%BeginDefaults
%%ViewingOrientation: 1 0 0 1
%%EndDefaults


%%BeginProlog
mark
 () () (201611192045) {setuserinfo} stopped
cleartomark
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_WinNT_ErrorHandler 5.0 0
/currentpacking where{pop/oldpack currentpacking def/setpacking where{pop false
setpacking}if}if/$brkpage 64 dict def $brkpage begin/prnt{dup type/stringtype
ne{=string cvs}if dup length 6 mul/tx exch def/ty 10 def currentpoint/toy exch
def/tox exch def 1 setgray newpath tox toy 2 sub moveto 0 ty rlineto tx 0
rlineto 0 ty neg rlineto closepath fill tox toy moveto 0 setgray show}bind def
/nl{currentpoint exch pop lmargin exch moveto 0 -10 rmoveto}def/=={/cp 0 def
typeprint nl}def/typeprint{dup type exec}readonly def/lmargin 72 def/rmargin 72
def/tprint{dup length cp add rmargin gt{nl/cp 0 def}if dup length cp add/cp
exch def prnt}readonly def/cvsprint{=string cvs tprint( )tprint}readonly def
/integertype{cvsprint}readonly def/realtype{cvsprint}readonly def/booleantype
{cvsprint}readonly def/operatortype{(--)tprint =string cvs tprint(-- )tprint}
readonly def/marktype{pop(-mark- )tprint}readonly def/dicttype{pop
(-dictionary- )tprint}readonly def/nulltype{pop(-null- )tprint}readonly def
/filetype{pop(-filestream- )tprint}readonly def/savetype{pop(-savelevel- )
tprint}readonly def/fonttype{pop(-fontid- )tprint}readonly def/nametype{dup
xcheck not{(/)tprint}if cvsprint}readonly def/stringtype{dup rcheck{(\()tprint
tprint(\))tprint}{pop(-string- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/arraytype{dup rcheck
{dup xcheck{({)tprint{typeprint}forall(})tprint}{([)tprint{typeprint}forall(])
tprint}ifelse}{pop(-array- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/packedarraytype{dup
rcheck{dup xcheck{({)tprint{typeprint}forall(})tprint}{([)tprint{typeprint}
forall(])tprint}ifelse}{pop(-packedarray- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/courier
/Courier findfont 10 scalefont def end errordict/handleerror{systemdict begin
$error begin $brkpage begin newerror{/newerror false store vmstatus pop pop 0
ne{grestoreall}if errorname(VMerror)ne{showpage}if initgraphics courier setfont
lmargin 720 moveto errorname(VMerror)eq{userdict/ehsave known{clear userdict
/ehsave get restore 2 vmreclaim}if vmstatus exch pop exch pop PrtVMMsg}{
(ERROR: )prnt errorname prnt nl(OFFENDING COMMAND: )prnt/command load prnt
$error/ostack known{nl nl(STACK:)prnt nl nl $error/ostack get aload length{==}
repeat}if}ifelse systemdict/showpage get exec(%%[ Error: )print errorname
=print(; OffendingCommand: )print/command load =print( ]%%)= flush}if end end
end}dup 0 systemdict put dup 4 $brkpage put bind readonly put/currentpacking
where{pop/setpacking where{pop oldpack setpacking}if}if
%%EndResource
userdict /Pscript_WinNT_Incr 230 dict dup begin put
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_FatalError 5.0 0
userdict begin/FatalErrorIf{{initgraphics findfont 1 index 0 eq{exch pop}{dup
length dict begin{1 index/FID ne{def}{pop pop}ifelse}forall/Encoding
{ISOLatin1Encoding}stopped{StandardEncoding}if def currentdict end
/ErrFont-Latin1 exch definefont}ifelse exch scalefont setfont counttomark 3 div
cvi{moveto show}repeat showpage quit}{cleartomark}ifelse}bind def end
%%EndResource
userdict begin/PrtVMMsg{vmstatus exch sub exch pop gt{[
(This job requires more memory than is available in this printer.)100 500
(Try one or more of the following, and then print again:)100 485
(For the output format, choose Optimize For Portability.)115 470
(In the Device Settings page, make sure the Available PostScript Memory is accurate.)
115 455(Reduce the number of fonts in the document.)115 440
(Print the document in parts.)115 425 12/Times-Roman showpage
(%%[ PrinterError: Low Printer VM ]%%)= true FatalErrorIf}if}bind def end
version cvi 2016 ge{/VM?{pop}bind def}{/VM? userdict/PrtVMMsg get def}ifelse
105000 VM?
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_Win_Basic 5.0 0
/d/def load def/,/load load d/~/exch , d/?/ifelse , d/!/pop , d/`/begin , d/^
/index , d/@/dup , d/+/translate , d/$/roll , d/U/userdict , d/M/moveto , d/-
/rlineto , d/&/currentdict , d/:/gsave , d/;/grestore , d/F/false , d/T/true ,
d/N/newpath , d/E/end , d/Ac/arc , d/An/arcn , d/A/ashow , d/D/awidthshow , d/C
/closepath , d/V/div , d/O/eofill , d/L/fill , d/I/lineto , d/-c/curveto , d/-M
/rmoveto , d/+S/scale , d/Ji/setfont , d/Lc/setlinecap , d/Lj/setlinejoin , d
/Lw/setlinewidth , d/Lm/setmiterlimit , d/sd/setdash , d/S/show , d/LH/showpage
, d/K/stroke , d/W/widthshow , d/R/rotate , d/L2? false/languagelevel where{pop
languagelevel 2 ge{pop true}if}if d L2?{/xS/xshow , d/yS/yshow , d/zS/xyshow ,
d}if/b{bind d}bind d/bd{bind d}bind d/xd{~ d}bd/ld{, d}bd/bn/bind ld/lw/Lw ld
/lc/Lc ld/lj/Lj ld/sg/setgray ld/ADO_mxRot null d/self & d/OrgMx matrix
currentmatrix d/reinitialize{: OrgMx setmatrix[/TextInit/GraphInit/UtilsInit
counttomark{@ where{self eq}{F}?{cvx exec}{!}?}repeat cleartomark ;}b
/initialize{`{/Pscript_Win_Data where{!}{U/Pscript_Win_Data & put}?/ADO_mxRot ~
d/TextInitialised? F d reinitialize E}{U/Pscript_Win_Data 230 dict @ ` put
/ADO_mxRot ~ d/TextInitialised? F d reinitialize}?}b/terminate{!{& self eq
{exit}{E}?}loop E}b/suspend/terminate , d/resume{` Pscript_Win_Data `}b U `
/lucas 21690 d/featurebegin{countdictstack lucas[}b/featurecleanup{stopped
{cleartomark @ lucas eq{! exit}if}loop countdictstack ~ sub @ 0 gt{{E}repeat}
{!}?}b E/snap{transform 0.25 sub round 0.25 add ~ 0.25 sub round 0.25 add ~
itransform}b/dsnap{dtransform round ~ round ~ idtransform}b/nonzero_round{@ 0.5
ge{round}{@ -0.5 lt{round}{0 ge{1}{-1}?}?}?}b/nonzero_dsnap{dtransform
nonzero_round ~ nonzero_round ~ idtransform}b U<04>cvn{}put/rr{1 ^ 0 - 0 ~ -
neg 0 - C}b/irp{4 -2 $ + +S fx 4 2 $ M 1 ^ 0 - 0 ~ - neg 0 -}b/rp{4 2 $ M 1 ^ 0
- 0 ~ - neg 0 -}b/solid{[]0 sd}b/g{@ not{U/DefIf_save save put}if U/DefIf_bool
2 ^ put}b/DefIf_El{if U/DefIf_bool get not @{U/DefIf_save get restore}if}b/e
{DefIf_El !}b/UDF{L2?{undefinefont}{!}?}b/UDR{L2?{undefineresource}{! !}?}b
/freeVM{/Courier findfont[40 0 0 -40 0 0]makefont Ji 2 vmreclaim}b/hfRedefFont
{findfont @ length dict `{1 ^/FID ne{d}{! !}?}forall & E @ ` ~{/CharStrings 1
dict `/.notdef 0 d & E d}if/Encoding 256 array 0 1 255{1 ^ ~/.notdef put}for d
E definefont !}bind d/hfMkCIDFont{/CIDFont findresource @ length 2 add dict `{1
^ @/FID eq ~ @/XUID eq ~/UIDBase eq or or{! !}{d}?}forall/CDevProc ~ d/Metrics2
16 dict d/CIDFontName 1 ^ d & E 1 ^ ~/CIDFont defineresource ![~]composefont !}
bind d
%%EndResource
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_Win_Utils_L2 5.0 0
/rf/rectfill , d/fx{1 1 dtransform @ 0 ge{1 sub 0.5}{1 add -0.5}? 3 -1 $ @ 0 ge
{1 sub 0.5}{1 add -0.5}? 3 1 $ 4 1 $ idtransform 4 -2 $ idtransform}b/BZ{4 -2 $
snap + +S fx rf}b/rs/rectstroke , d/rc/rectclip , d/UtilsInit{currentglobal{F
setglobal}if}b/scol{! setcolor}b/colspA/DeviceGray d/colspABC/DeviceRGB d
/colspRefresh{colspABC setcolorspace}b/SetColSpace{colspABC setcolorspace}b
/resourcestatus where{!/ColorRendering/ProcSet resourcestatus{! ! T}{F}?}{F}?
not{/ColorRendering<</GetHalftoneName{currenthalftone @/HalftoneName known{
/HalftoneName get}{!/none}?}bn/GetPageDeviceName{currentpagedevice @
/PageDeviceName known{/PageDeviceName get @ null eq{!/none}if}{!/none}?}bn
/GetSubstituteCRD{!/DefaultColorRendering/ColorRendering resourcestatus{! !
/DefaultColorRendering}{(DefaultColorRendering*){cvn exit}127 string
/ColorRendering resourceforall}?}bn>>/defineresource where{!/ProcSet
defineresource !}{! !}?}if/buildcrdname{/ColorRendering/ProcSet findresource `
mark GetHalftoneName @ type @/nametype ne ~/stringtype ne and{!/none}if(.)
GetPageDeviceName @ type @/nametype ne ~/stringtype ne and{!/none}if(.)5 ^ 0 5
-1 1{^ length add}for string 6 1 $ 5 ^ 5{~ 1 ^ cvs length 1 ^ length 1 ^ sub
getinterval}repeat ! cvn 3 1 $ ! ! E}b/definecolorrendering{~ buildcrdname ~
/ColorRendering defineresource !}b/findcolorrendering where{!}{
/findcolorrendering{buildcrdname @/ColorRendering resourcestatus{! ! T}{
/ColorRendering/ProcSet findresource ` GetSubstituteCRD E F}?}b}?
/selectcolorrendering{findcolorrendering !/ColorRendering findresource
setcolorrendering}b/G2UBegin{findresource/FontInfo get/GlyphNames2Unicode get
`}bind d/G2CCBegin{findresource/FontInfo get/GlyphNames2HostCode get `}bind d
/G2UEnd{E}bind d/AddFontInfoBegin{/FontInfo 8 dict @ `}bind d/AddFontInfo{
/GlyphNames2Unicode 16 dict d/GlyphNames2HostCode 16 dict d}bind d
/AddFontInfoEnd{E d}bind d/T0AddCFFMtx2{/CIDFont findresource/Metrics2 get ` d
E}bind d
%%EndResource
end
%%EndProlog

%%BeginSetup
statusdict begin (%%[ ProductName: ) print product print ( ]%%)= flush end
[ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ] false Pscript_WinNT_Incr dup /initialize get exec
featurebegin{
%%BeginNonPPDFeature: JobTimeout 0
0 /languagelevel where{pop languagelevel}{1}ifelse 2 ge{1 dict dup/JobTimeout  4 -1 roll put setuserparams}{statusdict/setjobtimeout get exec}ifelse
%%EndNonPPDFeature
}featurecleanup

featurebegin{
%%BeginNonPPDFeature: WaitTimeout 300
300 /languagelevel where{pop languagelevel}{1}ifelse 2 ge{1 dict dup/WaitTimeout 4 -1 roll put setuserparams}{statusdict/waittimeout 3 -1 roll put}ifelse
%%EndNonPPDFeature
}featurecleanup

featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIPaperPolicy PromptUser

  <</DeferredMediaSelection true>> setpagedevice
  <</Policies << /PageSize 2 /MediaType 2 >> >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *PageSize A4
<<
  /PageSize [595 842] /ImagingBBox null >> setpagedevice 
  false setedgetoedge
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSBitsPerPixel 2BitsPerPixel
2 setbitsperpixel
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIPrintMode 0rhit
<< /HWResolution[600 600]
  /PostRenderingEnhance false>> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Duplex None
<</Duplex false>>setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *ColorModel CMYK
(cmyk) RCsetdevicecolor
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSRGBcorrect DetailBright
(precision-dark) RCsetrgbrevision
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSColorRendDict Auto
(auto) RCsetcolorprofile
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSDitherType Auto
(auto) RCsethalftonetype
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSBlackMode gray
(gray) (gray) (off)  /RDeviceProcSet 
/ProcSet findresource /SetPureBlack get exec
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSBlackOverPrint False
(off) RCsetblackoverprint
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RPSColorSep None
(none) RCsetprintseparation
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Rcmyksimulation Off
(None) RCsetcmyksimulation
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Rimagesm Off
(off) /RDeviceProcSet /ProcSet findresource /SetImageInterpolate get exec
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIRotateBy180 Off

0 /RDeviceProcSet /ProcSet findresource /SetImageRotation get exec

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIOrientOvr Off

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Collate True
<</Collate true
  /CollateDetails <</Type 6 /AlignSet false>>
  >>setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *MediaType Auto
<< /MediaType (Auto) >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *OutputBin Default
<</OutputType null>>setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *StapleLocation None
<< /Staple 0 >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIPunch None
<< /Punch 0 >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIZfold None
<< /Fold 0 >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIWatermark Off

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIWMText Confidential
userdict /RPS_WMdict get begin
 /RPS_WM_str (CONFIDENTIAL) def end
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIwmFont HelveticaB
userdict /RPS_WMdict get begin
 /RPS_WM_font /Helvetica-Bold def end
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIwmSize 36
userdict /RPS_WMdict get begin
 /RPS_WM_size 36 def end
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIwmAngle 45Deg
userdict /RPS_WMdict get begin
 /RPS_WM_angle 45 def end
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *RIwmTextStyle Gray
userdict /RPS_WMdict get begin
   /RPS_WM_color { 0 setgray }  bind  def
   /RPS_WM_Pattern {
    <<
        /PatternType 1
        /PaintType 1
        /TilingType 3
        /BBox [ 0 0 1 1 ]
        /XStep 1 
        /YStep 1 
        /PaintProc {
            begin
                RPS_WM_color
                8 8 true [ 8 0 0 -8 0 8 ]
                <88002200 88002200> imagemask
            end
        }
    >> [ 1 0 0 -1 0 1 ] makepattern
    setpattern }
   bind def
   /RPS_WM_draw {   %% RPS_WM_mask
    RPS_WM_str false charpath fill
  } bind def end
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Support8CharPassword True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Resolution 600dpi

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportDocUiReplace True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportStoreandPrint True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportStoredPrint True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *AutoConfig True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportSamplePrint True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportSecurePrint True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportDocumentBox True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *SupportHoldPrint True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *HardDisk Installed

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *LCTDetail NotInstalled

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Finisher NotInstalled

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *BookletProcessor False

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *Mailbox NotInstalled

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *ZfoldingUnit False

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *MultiHolePunchUnit False

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *AutoConfigPaperSizeDisable True

%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
1 setlinecap 1 setlinejoin
/mysetup [ 72 600 V 0 0 -72 600 V 11.99905 830.00128 ] def 
%%EndSetup

userdict begin /ehsave save def end
%%EndPageComments
%%BeginPageSetup
/DeviceRGB dup setcolorspace /colspABC exch def
mysetup concat colspRefresh
%%EndPageSetup

%%BeginPageSetup 
/DeviceRGB dup setcolorspace /colspABC exch def 
/framenup F d 
%%EndPageSetup 
/DeviceGray dup setcolorspace /colspABC exch def
0.297 0 scol Pscript_WinNT_Incr begin
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_Text 5.0 0
/TextInit{TextInitialised? not{/Pscript_Windows_Font & d/TextInitialised? T d
/fM[1 0 0 1 0 0]d/mFM matrix d/iMat[1 0 0.212557 1 0 0]d}if}b/copyfont{1 ^
length add dict `{1 ^/FID ne{d}{! !}?}forall & E}b/EncodeDict 11 dict d/bullets
{{/bullet}repeat}b/rF{3 copyfont @ ` ~ EncodeDict ~ get/Encoding ~ 3 ^/0 eq{&
/CharStrings known{CharStrings/Eth known not{! EncodeDict/ANSIEncodingOld get}
if}if}if d E}b/mF{@ 7 1 $ findfont ~{@/Encoding get @ StandardEncoding eq{! T}{
{ISOLatin1Encoding}stopped{! F}{eq}?{T}{@ ` T 32 1 127{Encoding 1 ^ get
StandardEncoding 3 -1 $ get eq and}for E}?}?}{F}?{1 ^ ~ rF}{0 copyfont}? 6 -2 $
! ! ~ !/pd_charset @ where{~ get 128 eq{@ FDV 2 copy get @ length array copy
put pd_CoverFCRange}if}{!}? 2 ^ ~ definefont fM 5 4 -1 $ put fM 4 0 put fM
makefont Pscript_Windows_Font 3 1 $ put}b/sLT{: Lw -M currentpoint snap M 0 - 0
Lc K ;}b/xUP null d/yUP null d/uW null d/xSP null d/ySP null d/sW null d/sSU{N
/uW ~ d/yUP ~ d/xUP ~ d}b/sU{xUP yUP uW sLT}b/sST{N/sW ~ d/ySP ~ d/xSP ~ d}b/sT
{xSP ySP sW sLT}b/sR{: + R 0 0 M}b/sRxy{: matrix astore concat 0 0 M}b/eR/; , d
/AddOrigFP{{&/FontInfo known{&/FontInfo get length 6 add}{6}? dict `
/WinPitchAndFamily ~ d/WinCharSet ~ d/OrigFontType ~ d/OrigFontStyle ~ d
/OrigFontName ~ d & E/FontInfo ~ d}{! ! ! ! !}?}b/mFS{makefont
Pscript_Windows_Font 3 1 $ put}b/mF42D{0 copyfont `/FontName ~ d 2 copy ~ sub 1
add dict `/.notdef 0 d 2 copy 1 ~{@ 3 ^ sub Encoding ~ get ~ d}for & E
/CharStrings ~ d ! ! & @ E/FontName get ~ definefont}b/mF42{15 dict ` @ 4 1 $
FontName ~ d/FontType 0 d/FMapType 2 d/FontMatrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]d 1 ^ 254 add 255
idiv @ array/Encoding ~ d 0 1 3 -1 $ 1 sub{@ Encoding 3 1 $ put}for/FDepVector
Encoding length array d/CharStrings 2 dict `/.notdef 0 d & E d 0 1 Encoding
length 1 sub{@ @ 10 lt{! FontName length 1 add string}{100 lt{FontName length 2
add string}{FontName length 3 add string}?}? @ 0 FontName @ length string cvs
putinterval @ 3 -1 $ @ 4 1 $ 3 string cvs FontName length ~ putinterval cvn 1 ^
256 mul @ 255 add 3 -1 $ 4 ^ findfont mF42D FDepVector 3 1 $ put}for & @ E
/FontName get ~ definefont ! ! ! mF}b/mF_OTF_V{~ ! ~ ! 4 -1 $ ! findfont 2 ^ ~
definefont fM @ @ 4 6 -1 $ neg put 5 0 put 90 matrix R matrix concatmatrix
makefont Pscript_Windows_Font 3 1 $ put}b/mF_TTF_V{3{~ !}repeat 3 -1 $ !
findfont 1 ^ ~ definefont Pscript_Windows_Font 3 1 $ put}b/UmF{L2?
{Pscript_Windows_Font ~ undef}{!}?}b/UmF42{@ findfont/FDepVector get{/FontName
get undefinefont}forall undefinefont}b
%%EndResource
end reinitialize
Pscript_WinNT_Incr begin
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_Encoding256 5.0 0
/CharCol256Encoding[/.notdef/breve/caron/dotaccent/dotlessi/fi/fl/fraction
/hungarumlaut/Lslash/lslash/minus/ogonek/ring/Zcaron/zcaron/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/space/exclam/quotedbl/numbersign
/dollar/percent/ampersand/quotesingle/parenleft/parenright/asterisk/plus/comma
/hyphen/period/slash/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight/nine/colon
/semicolon/less/equal/greater/question/at/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S
/T/U/V/W/X/Y/Z/bracketleft/backslash/bracketright/asciicircum/underscore/grave
/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z/braceleft/bar/braceright
/asciitilde/.notdef/Euro/.notdef/quotesinglbase/florin/quotedblbase/ellipsis
/dagger/daggerdbl/circumflex/perthousand/Scaron/guilsinglleft/OE/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/quoteleft/quoteright/quotedblleft/quotedblright/bullet
/endash/emdash/tilde/trademark/scaron/guilsinglright/oe/.notdef/.notdef
/Ydieresis/.notdef/exclamdown/cent/sterling/currency/yen/brokenbar/section
/dieresis/copyright/ordfeminine/guillemotleft/logicalnot/.notdef/registered
/macron/degree/plusminus/twosuperior/threesuperior/acute/mu/paragraph
/periodcentered/cedilla/onesuperior/ordmasculine/guillemotright/onequarter
/onehalf/threequarters/questiondown/Agrave/Aacute/Acircumflex/Atilde/Adieresis
/Aring/AE/Ccedilla/Egrave/Eacute/Ecircumflex/Edieresis/Igrave/Iacute
/Icircumflex/Idieresis/Eth/Ntilde/Ograve/Oacute/Ocircumflex/Otilde/Odieresis
/multiply/Oslash/Ugrave/Uacute/Ucircumflex/Udieresis/Yacute/Thorn/germandbls
/agrave/aacute/acircumflex/atilde/adieresis/aring/ae/ccedilla/egrave/eacute
/ecircumflex/edieresis/igrave/iacute/icircumflex/idieresis/eth/ntilde/ograve
/oacute/ocircumflex/otilde/odieresis/divide/oslash/ugrave/uacute/ucircumflex
/udieresis/yacute/thorn/ydieresis]def EncodeDict/256 CharCol256Encoding put
%%EndResource
end reinitialize

%%IncludeResource: font TimesNewRomanPSMT
F /F0 0 /256 T /TimesNewRomanPSMT mF 
/F0S64YFFFFFF9C F0 [100.352 0 0 -100 0 0 ] mFS
F0S64YFFFFFF9C Ji 
169 121 M (Test)[61 44 39  0]xS 
LH
(%%[Page: 1]%%) = 
%%PageTrailer

%%Trailer
%%DocumentNeededResources: 
%%+ font TimesNewRomanPSMT
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: 
%%+ procset Pscript_WinNT_ErrorHandler 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_FatalError 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_Win_Basic 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_Win_Utils_L2 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_Text 5.0 0
%%+ procset Pscript_Encoding256 5.0 0
Pscript_WinNT_Incr dup /terminate get exec
ehsave restore
(%%[LastPage]%%) = 
%%EOF
%-12345X@PJL EOJ
```

Comment: My ghostscript renders it black, it's not a problem of the pdf conversion but of the printer driver.

Comment: I deleted and re-installed printer Infotec driver using windows update. Problem persists. Printer is set to print color. What driver setting forces printer to create monochrome file? Is it possible to use some other psotscript printer driver in windows to create ps file in other way ? Or can this ps file post-processed to force colors to appear ?

Comment: Earlierdays we typically used an Apple Laserwrite if PS was needed. I have no idea how and why yours produces a colourless PS output. Postprocessing depends on how easily you can identify the places that you want coloured inside the PS. I suspect that anything else should be easier.

Comment: You cannot realistically 'add' colour to a monochrome PostScript program, how would you know where the colour should go ? Yes you can use a different printer driver, they all use the same actual PostScript engine in Windows. But as Stefan correctly says, this is a configuration problem in your WIndows installation, nothing to do with Ghostscript, PostScript, PDF or visual foxpro. Nobody is going to be able to help you with the configuration really, you'll have to sit down and go through it yourself. Look at every tab, press every button etc.

Comment: @StefanHegny I have checked all driver settings. It worked one time if I installed HP LJ A3 and infotec printers, removed and re-installed infotec. However at next day it suddenly switches back to monochrome. Some time ago Adobe also produces PS driver for Windows. Maybe there is some simple setting which I'm missing or third party PS driver for windows? Or is it possible to create PDF from PCL or other non-PS windows output format?

Comment: I deleted all printers in windows and used Print server / Drivers to remove all printer driver packages. After re-installing Infotec PS result is still monochrome. How to fix this ?